# wkhtmltopdf falis for 1000+ pages ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, wkhtmltopdf

Generating a pdf of 1000+ pages fails in case of header supplied.
layouts/header is a header.pdf.haml file.
After going through various suggestions, increased the open files limit on ubuntu also didn't work.

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.xlsx
  format.pdf { render pdf: "Test report", dispoistion: :attachment,
      :show_as_html => (params[:d].present? && params[:d] == "true"),
      layout: "pdf.html.haml",
      margin: {
        top: 38
      },
      header: {
        spacing: 2,
        html: {
          template: 'layouts/header',
          formats:  [:pdf],
          handlers: [:haml],
          layout: nil,
          locals: {
            title: "Test Report"
          }
        }
    }
  }
end
```

> RuntimeError (Failed to execute:
>   ["/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/bin/wkhtmltopdf", "-q", "--page-size",
>   "Letter", "--margin-top", "38", "--header-spacing", "2",
>   "--header-html",
>   "file:////tmp/wicked_header_pdf20180828-94225-2oante.html",
>   "--footer-left", "Test Online", "--footer-right", "Page [page] of
>   [topage]", "file:////tmp/wicked_pdf20180828-94225-f0g5x0.html",
>   "/tmp/wicked_pdf_generated_file20180828-94225-80q49r.pdf"] Error: PDF
>   could not be generated! PaintDevice: Cannot destroy paint device that
>   is being painted ):

Added, could anyone suggest a way how to make header point to local path.
As suggested in https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/2093#issuecomment-167955213

Comment: Can you please add error in Question ?

Comment: Added, could anyone suggest a way how to make header point to local path.
As suggested in https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/2093#issuecomment-167955213

Comment: try `ulimit -n 2048` command in terminal. then try to generate pdf again. let me know if it works or not

Comment: Tried by increasing the limit to 2048, 10k as well.It didnt work out

Comment: What if your remove header and footer and then try again to generate pdf ?

Comment: Without header and footer 1100 pages takes 3 minuts, and get downlaoded.

Comment: Didn't you use background job ?

Comment: No, we are not using background jobs. We have to generate pdf on fly, since in every minute that data going to dynamic.

Comment: Yeah, but if it takes time of 3 minutes, then you should use background, user won't  wait for 3 minutes to complete one request